# Remove and Add comma in String at Dynamic way

Tags: c#, selenium, unit-testing

I have address separated by comma like address1,address2,city,country I need to remove comma if the any of value is empty or null at run time.

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample input and the output you want to get for it.

Comment: so what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched?

Comment: I have tried the linq , split methods by comma , replace method but nothing worked for me  the address is stored in list like [address line 1, address line 2, zipcode, city, country] , the problem is that I don't know what value is empty at run time I want to get values if city is empty then i want this output address = [addressline1, addressline2, zipcode, country]

Answer (score 0):

Basic method, but i think you could make better if you search

```
string mee = "address1,,city,country";
        string[] arr = mee.Split(',');
        string final = string.Empty;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {                
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(arr[i]))
                continue;

            final += i == 0 ? arr[i] : $",{arr[i]}";

        }
```

Or perhaps with System.Linq (but you must test all possibilities)

```
            string final = String.Join(",", mee.Split(',').Where((x) => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)));
```